How can I automatically sanitize user input in a large React app with many forms using React Hook Form?
In a large React application that contains many forms with multiple input fields where users enter data. I'm using React Hook Form (RHF) for handling the form state and validation, but I’ve run into an issue with input sanitization.
By default, React Hook Form doesn’t sanitize input data, and in a complex application with numerous forms and input fields, it would be very cumbersome and error-prone to sanitize each input field individually.
The Problem:

Sanitization at the field level would be difficult to manage for
every single form in the application.
I want to ensure that the data entered by users is safe and cleaned
(to prevent XSS attacks or malicious input) before being submitted.
I'm looking for an automatic or global solution to sanitize all form
inputs consistently across the app.

What I’ve Considered So Far:

I know I can manually sanitize input data in the onSubmit handler of
each form, but this feels like a repetitive task, especially with
many forms. I could sanitize each field during the onChange event,
but that would add extra complexity and boilerplate.

What I’m Looking For:

A solution that sanitizes inputs globally for all forms
in the app. Ideally, I would like to avoid manually sanitizing each
form field. Best practices for handling input sanitization in a
scalable and efficient manner when using React Hook Form.

